# Images not served in production via image_tag in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, digital-ocean

I deployed my app to production and noticed that images are not served from image_tag, but are served if I use asset_path. I have my images under app/assets/images. On production I precompile them so they are in public/assets and have names such as 'image_name-fk3r23039423-0e9232.png'.

When I look at html code generated I see that my image_tag's src is

```
/images/logo
```

while asset_path generates this:

```
/assets/login-bg1-01eead5b47afcb7e0a951a3668ec3921e8df3f4507f70599f1b84d5efc971855.jpg
```

So it is correct. So I am interested why I can not serve images using image_tag 'image-name'?

Here is my production.rb

```
config.serve_static_files = true

config.assets.compile = false

config.assets.digest = true
```

Comment: We ran into this on GitLab in https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/28743

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I resolved this by adding extension to the file. I.e I did this:

```html
<%= image_tag 'logo.png'%> # added .png
```

I don't know why it didn't worked without extension as in development. So I suppose this logo image is now served from application assets, not from public.

Comment: I ran into this same issue. Idk why it happens, though.

Comment: It happens because in development when Rails does not find the asset in the manifest file, it falls back on another mechanism (the environment resolver) that is smart enough to figure out the extension. In production this fallback is not active.

Answer (score 1):

I had an similar issue and the difference was I had to change the file extension from `jpeg` to `jpg` in case that helps anyone.